# Как удалить виджет по его objectName в PyQT5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Как я могу удалить виджет, имея его objectName? Сейчас код выдает ошибку из-за того, что я в метод removeWidget() передаю строку, но как мне сделать так, чтобы removeWidget() удалял виджет?

```
        self.senderText = self.sender().objectName()
        self.selectedTask.setText(self.sender().text())
        font = self.selectedTask.font()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.noteText.setPlainText('')

        self.deletetaskButton.clicked.connect(self.deleteTask)
        self.selectdateButton.clicked.connect(self.selectDate)

    def deleteTask(self):
        self.tasksList.removeWidget(self.senderText)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Используйте findChild для поиска виджета по его objectName. Сразу обращу внимание, что виджет ищется только среди непосредственных потомков родителя. В реальных условиях возможно понадобится делать рекурсивный поиск.

В Примере создаются несколько кнопок с ObjectName "button1", "button2" и т.д. Введите имя в lineedit и нажмите кнопку "delete by name". Если потомок найдется, он будет удален (можете ввести "button1" чтобы удалить кнопку или "lineedit", тогда будет удалена строка ввода)

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, QObject

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def btnClicked(self):
        # поиск потомка self по его имени из lineedit
        resbutton = self.findChild(QObject, self.lineedit.text())
        if resbutton:
            resbutton.deleteLater()

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(400, 400))
        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        self.grid_layout = QGridLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(self.grid_layout)

        for i in range(1,10):
            button = QPushButton(f"i'am button{i}")
            button.setObjectName(f"button{i}")
            self.grid_layout.addWidget(button, i, 0)
        self.lineedit = QLineEdit()
        self.lineedit.setObjectName("lineedit")
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.lineedit, 10, 0)
        self.button = QPushButton("delete by name")
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.button, 10, 1)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```